# How to to convert HTML to PDF in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf-generation

I'm going to use shared hosting to host my Laravel project, maximum library use whtmltopdf module in unix system That's why I'm not sure to use this (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

How to to convert HTML to PDF in laravel?

Answer (score 1):

You would use it like:

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Your HTML Here</h1>');
return $pdf->stream();
```

Which would return a PDF to the browser or you could use the Facade that comes bundled and use:

```
return PDF::loadFile(public_path().'/your_html.html')->stream('download.pdf');
```

The [README](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) outlines what you need to add to your project to get started.

Answer (score 0):

use this package:
[vattan/apdf][1]

It easy and support utf-8 characters and compatible with laravel
[1]: https://packagist.org/packages/vatttan/apdf